# Minimal Bash on Install

Tags: bash, boot

I have a USB with Elementary 3.01 (Freya). I am able to successfully run the liveCD (which I am in now) and am able to perform the install of the OS onto my PC. Upon what appears to be a successful install of the OS, I reboot and get the following:

```
Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

Now of course I have gone digging to see what the go is and it appears that this is a common issue. I can validate that the USB is formatted correctly as I have gone and installed the OS successfully on my old laptop.

I have read on AskUbuntu `/questions/159846/tried-to-boot-ubuntu-but-the-grub-rescue-shows-up-instead` and on Unix `/questions/148041/recovering-from-grub-rescue-crash`

But this has yet to help me. I am not attempting to dual boot the OS so I have used the automatic partitioning tool to create my drive. When I run the `ls` command from `grub` it gives me some error accessing `(hd0)`, I cannot upload the image due to no PC, but will advise once I can.

Some key settings I am using on my Gigabyte Motherboard:

> Windows 8 Feature has been set to Other OS and not Windows 8 or Windows 8 WHQL
>
> Boot Mode selection has been set to Legacy and not UEFI or UEFI and Legacy
>
> The Storage Boot Option Control has been set to Legacy First, not UEFI first
>
> XCHI Mode has been set to Smart Auto and not auto, disabled or enabled
>
> XCHI Handoff has been set to enable and not disable
>
> EHCI Handoff has been set to disable and not enable

Due to not having an operational PC (that laptop is far too slow for use), there is little research I can do, as testing something requires me to down the machine for 10-25 minutes per try.

I could attempt to use another Linux Distro but that would mean re-downloading the .iso and then making a bootable USB. If this issue could be fixed I'd prefer to stick with it.

**Update 1**

From within Elementary OS on my laptop I installed `unetbotin`, ran as root and formatted my USB. I successfully installed the OS in UEFI mode and rebooted to get to the bash screen. I then followed these steps:

`ls` to identify `(hd2,gpt2)` which has the `boot/` directory and `vmlinuz` folder.

`set root=(hd2,gpt2)/boot` was the next command ran.

`isnmod linux` followed by `linux (hd2,gpt2)/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-26-generic` (also tried the `.efi` one)

The next command was `initrd (hd2,gpt2)/boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-26-generic` and then `boot` and prompt was brought to `initramfs`, cool.

This successfully started `BusyBox`. From here the PC stopped recognizing my keyboard, even in BIOS/Legacy mode.

**Update 2**
I am sick of using the laptop. I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 via a Live CD. Upon reboot I get to the GRUB menu (which still has the entries for Elementary) but booting to UBUNTU fails. I enter `advanced Ubuntu` and boot to generic and all is well.

I cannot get to the settings for Display as it crashes and I cannot use the shortcut key `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T` to launch terminal, but that's okay. I have installed Grub Repair and will boot to the live environment and run.

At the moment I am performing the standard updates to the system (which I hope are some bug fixes) and I will get the additional drivers. Once I have a somewhat operational Linux OS I will format the secondary SSD in my PC and try to install Elementary to that, at least having a fallback when it fails.

**Update 3** Both Arch Linux and Manjaro linux result in a terminal with just `_` on the screen with no input. I have also attempted to install Ubuntu 15.04 and Lubuntu 15.04 but fail due to some weird `USB 1-10 fail to read -71`error. I am now starting to think either there is some major hardware clash or it's the operator.

I am going to download Mint and Sabayon to see what I can do.

Comment: To help identify if this is an OS specific issue, I am going to attempt to download Manjaro and use `dd` to format a USB. If that install works I will be able to identify if it an issue with this OS, or more a setting on my BIOS/MoBo.

Comment: Within Elementsary I have downloaded `Arch`, `Manjaro`, `Elementary` and `Mint`. I have used `unetbootin` to format the elementary install and will try again. The steps I go through will be posted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the steps of Update 2 did not help, but once another GRUB menu was present, I was able to boot into the OS.

This is not the technical fix to this fault, however this was my fix.